# Difference between Tensorfloat and ImageFeatureValue

Tags: windows-machine-learning

When using the Windows-Machine-Learning library, the input and output to the onnx models is often either `TensorFloat` or `ImageFeatureValue` format.

My question: What is the difference between these? It seems like I am able to change the form of the input in the automatically created `model.cs` file after onnx import (for body pose detection) from `TensorFloat` to `ImageFeatureValue` and the code still runs. This makes it e.g. easier to work with videoframes, since I can then create my input via `ImageFeatureValue.CreateFromVideoFrame(frame)`.
Is there a reason why this might lead to problems and what are the differences between these when using videoframes as input, I don't see it from the documentation? Or why does the model.cs script create a `TensorFloat` instead of an `ImageFeatureValue` in the first place anyway if the input is a videoframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/bind-a-model).

> If Windows ML does not support your model's color format or pixel range, then you can implement conversions and tensorization. You'll create an NCHW four-dimensional tensor for 32-bit floats for your input value. See the Custom Tensorization Sample for an example of how to do this.